# Power BI Embed -- Hide string Param URL filter on Filter Pane(Report Embedded via REST API)

Tags: powerbi-embedded

Scenario: My report is Embedded onto my organization website where till now I have been hiding the filter panel as I am unable to hide/ restrict user input for my AccountID column used as a string param URL filter.

But now I have drill through within the same report wherein I need the filter pane to erase the drill through filter selected value on the drilled through page to view entire results for that page visuals.

Any help/ suggested ref. Links with these below questions is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

**Q1(Preferred): How to hide/restrict user input for ONLY the string param URL filter on the Filter pane?

Q2: How do I clear the Drill through filter value without the filter pane? (If Q1 is not Possible I again have to hide back the filter pane).**

Comment: What you want is not possible. In such case you should use [RLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls) instead of URL filters.

Comment: Thanks alot @AndreyNikolov. Every though the answer is not the way I expected but atleast got an answer that it is not possible. Will Implement RLS at my end. Thanks again mate.

Comment: Hi, 2 years later is this still not possible and is there a feature request up for voting available yet? Just tried and still cannot hide.